# How to exit help in vim

Tags: vim

I just used the help files in vim and now I am stuck in help.

`:q` Exits the entire program and I am getting tired of having to close and reopen vim every time I use help. I would prefer a command that can close help and return me to the program I am writing.

I have trouble searching `google.com` because the search string `exit help in vim` obviously returns articles about exiting vim itself, something I have became very good at.

Does anyone know how to do this?

EDIT: I must have been somehow getting stuck in the split screen thing. That's why I was unable to get out of the help via `:q`

Comment: [Stack Overflow: Helping One Million Developers Exit Vim](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/23/stack-overflow-helping-one-million-developers-exit-vim/), [How to exit the Vim editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11828270/995714), [How do I quit from Vi?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3334/44425)

Comment: "...exiting vim itself, something I have become very good at." 

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`:q` is already the solution.

It closes not the whole vim session, but only the active window (split section within `vim`). If this is window is the help, only the help will be closed. If your document is active, the document will be closed.

If this is the last non-help window, the help will close as well -- which means `vim` is closed.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> followed by a cursor key to make sure your cursor is in the help window. Then try `:q` again.

Answer (score 21):

Recent Vims have the `:helpclose` command (this needs a Vim 7.4.449)

Comment: This is elegant, clear cut and avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 15):

`:q` is a little bit annoying since this is a readonly buffer. And I believe people rarely need to record a macro in help buffer.

So I'd like to map `q` to `:q`:

```
autocmd FileType help noremap <buffer> q :q<cr>
```

Comment: This is what I came in for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, although I agree that like many other more modern read only windows, it would be more natural if we could quit it with just pressing <kbd>q</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You must have somehow arrived at a sole help window. Usually, `:help` splits a window, and a `:q` in that window will just close the help, and return to the other window.

Or, you've typed the `:q` while in the *other* window, not the help. Vim doesn't "count" help windows as full windows, and will quit completely when only help windows would be left.

There are quite some window management commands; for example, `:close` is a variant of `:quit` that won't exit Vim. Though initially confusing, learn how to use them, as they are very powerful. `:help windows` has all the information.

Answer (score 2):

`:bd` will unload the current buffer (exit help) and return you to the last used buffer.

The command will not exit `vim`.

For example, the commands:

```
:help :bd
:only
:bd
```

will not exit `vim` despite the session having only 1 window.

Comment: Yes, it works! It works also with help window opened in a new tab: :tab help foo. But it does not look logical because help is absent in the list returned by :buffers command...

Answer (score 1):

I combined previous answers to get:

```
autocmd FileType help noremap <buffer> q :bd<CR>
```

or in lua:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "FileType", {
        pattern = {"help"},
        command = "noremap <buffer> q :bd<CR>",
    }
)
```

Works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but there is a shortcut for `:q` which is `ZQ`. `ZQ` is quit without saving. In the same way if you want to quit with save, then use `ZZ`(this is similar to `:wq`).